# How to get only the Surname in a range of cells?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet having a column of names. Now, in another sheet I want to have the surnames from the aforementioned column to be displayed in a dropdown. How can I do this?

The names look like this:

`Surname, FirstName`

And there are also people from the same household having the same surnames. There are no people with the same surname that belong to different households. So I kind of want to get the surnames to identify that household.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a single array formula referencing that list of names, that only pulls the surname portion using regexextract like this:

```
=IFERROR(UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"^(.*),"))))
```

To explain, the regexextract, I feel is a lighter formula and slightly simpler than using a split function for two reasons:

A split function would require you put both names to two separate cells, and unfortunately split function does not work with arrayformula.

But since regex does - the regex I specified is basically saying grab any text `(.*)` from the beginning of the cell `^` up until that comma `,`.

I then wrap the whole function in unique, so you dont have to deal with a ton of duplicates in your dropdown.

Following that I used `Data Validation` to point to the range of these unique surnames.

And just for fun at the end I finalized it with a `FILTER` function that would populate all the corresponding cells based on the surname chosen from the dropdown using this formula:

```
=FILTER(A:A,REGEXMATCH(A:A,C1)=TRUE)
```

To wrap all this information up, here is a sample image of what it looks like in the end:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! May I know where you studied these stuffs for Google Spreadsheet? It will be a very valuable resource for me

Comment: To be completely honest almost everything I've learned has been case by case and trial and error through many many projects for work over the last two years.  Im a data analyst so im constantly constantly cleaning and transforming Data.  But if i find Anything good I'll add it on here for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to split the names into another column. Let's say your names column is in A1, set the following formula in B1 and copy it in the next cells of the B row  :

```
=SPLIT(A1;",")
```

Then, you can define your dropdown list in another sheet as explained here : https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103